# How can I tweak a vector by direction of another vector?

Tags: c++, math, vector, physics

I'm working on a simple little game/simulation where I want to bounce a ball.  I'm trying to make the ball bounce not quite realistically, but more in a "game universe" way.

I have these variables to work with:

```
Vector ball_direction; // Direction the ball was moving in prior to impact
Vector ball_bounce_direction; // New direction of the ball computed from the collided face's normal
Vector collide_face_normal; // The normal of the collided face
Vector collide_face_perp; // perpendicular to the normal of the collided face
Vector gravity; // The gravity of the world-- doesn't really factor in since I want to do this operation based on the collision normal
```

So basically what I want to do is:

multiply ball_bounce_direction by .6 in the direction of collide_face_normal.
multiply ball_bounce_direction by 1.0 in the direction of collide_face_perp.

So a bouncing ball on a flat surface, I want the bounces to get smaller, while it completely maintains its sideways velocity.

Cans someone tell me what I need to do to ball_bounce_direction to achieve this?

Comment: What is the question exactly? The math behind this? (in that case, this is not really the place to ask) How to do it in C++? (if so, what is `Vector`?)

Comment: Vector is just a class with float x, float y, float z in it (and helper functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think of the dot product as "the magnitude of a vector in the direction of another vector", you can break `ball_bounce_direction` into two parts (I'm assuming you have a `dot` function):

```
Vector bbd_norm = ball_bounce_direction.dot(collide_face_normal)*ball_bounce_direction;
Vector bbd_perp = ball_bounce_direction.dot(collide_face_perp)*ball_bounce_direction;
```

This works because `collide_face_*` vectors are perpendicular, then you can build a new vector:

```
ball_bounce_direction = 0.6*bbd_norm + bbd_perp;
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the explanation.